# Requests in test for flask app is has no files

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to make unit tests for a flask app where it uploads a file (or multiple files) Below is what I have so far but I have tried multiple variations of posting the file

```
file_storage = FileStorage(stream=f, filename='replays')
        response = self.context.post('/api/upload', data={'files':(file_storage, 'replays')},
```

No matter what I do the requests.files is always empty while form is filled with the data I need.

I can not use requests.post as I need synchronous access to the call that I am testing.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue. This is the solution

```
# create your request like you normally would for upload
r = Request('POST', LOCAL_URL + '/api/upload',
            files={'replays': ('filename', io.Bytes(file))})

# build it
prepped = r.prepare()

# extract data needed for content
content_data = list(prepped.headers._store.items())
content_length = content_data[0][1][1]
content_type = content_data[1][1][1]

# add the body as an input stream and use the existing values
response = self.context.post('/api/upload', 
                             input_stream=io.BytesIO(prepped.body),
                             content_length=content_length,
                             content_type=content_type)
```